# Python ssh program not working due to different path separator on linux and windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, path, cross-platform

I am using MacOS to develop a Python2.7 application that uses `paramiko` to connect to a remote linux machine. Now, I gave my early code to a Microsoft Windows user to test, and immediately ran into the problem that `os.path.join` by default uses `\` as a separator in the path, when the application calls a command to be executed on the remote machine. So, I have to make sure to use the correct separator when doing operations on linux, while using the default separator on the local machine.

I'm thinking the easiest solution here is to just define my own `joinpath` function that always uses `/`as separator, and just call this function whenever the operation is being done remotely.

```
def joinpath(*args):
    return "/".join(args)
```

Or is there a better and more general of dealing with such a situation?

Comment: What path are you joining? Why don't you use Python's path joining?

Comment: using `os.path.join` resulted in something like `/home/user\software`, which gives an error when the path points to something on a remote linux computer.

Comment: Give an example of `args` that causes that. I think that you had some slashes or backslashes in your strings there before passing it. (e.g. "/home/user" and "software" of course will be joined as `/home/user\software` but it's not a problem with `os.path.join` but with your arguments!)

Comment: "os.path.join by default uses \ as a separator in the path, when the application is operating on the linux machine" - is impossible as the code is running on Linux and Python will use Linux separators then. Doesn't matter that's a remote machine (I even checked it as I have a Windows machine with ssh to a Linux machine with Python interpreter opened at the moment :P ).

Comment: Trust me, no backslashes were in the arguments. Example using `paramiko`: `with self.sftp_client.open(os.path.join(workdir, jobname+ext)) as f:`. This is being called from a Windows computer, but the sftp client opens a file on a remote linux machine. So the Windows separator is used to join to make a path for the linux machine.

Comment: I never work on windows but perhaps `pathlib.PosixPath` or friends can be of help to you

Answer (score 1):

> when the application is operating on the linux machine

This sentence basically means that Python is running on Linux. While this:

> This is being called from a Windows computer, but the sftp client opens a file on a remote linux machine

was actually what this is all about.

---

So:

`os` module operates on your OS (where the Python is running), giving you OS-specific and correct results

SSH (including SFTP) servers do not provide what CLI they use, that includes separators. They just give you a common interface to connect (and in case of SFTP, handle file transfer) but the rest is basically your problem. - I've dealt with network devices over ssh using Python myself, I had to e.g. manually deal with recognising errors etc because the output is text only.

That means, if you know that you'll be connecting to Linux machines only, use that join of yours (probably add a bit more, in case you have a dir path that ends in "/" - in your case, this will result in "//" in the path).

If you will connect both to Windows and Linux, do a fallback - catch the error (or manually find it in the output, I haven't worked with paramiko so I don't know how it dealt with it), and use another separator as a fallback and remember it for that session.